# Create a collection with the last 500 items in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I used the Helpdesk app template to create a helpdesk for my company. We've reached 500 tickets on the SharePoint list and the new tickets are not showing up on the app. I figure this is because of the 500 rows limit.

This is the App `OnStart` code right now:

```
Collect(AllTickets,HelpDesk);
```

How can I modify this so the gallery displays the last 500 tickets instead of the first 500?

I figure I can use a sort and filter on the Collect to create the AllTickets collection with the last 500 rows but I don't know the Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use Power Apps formula like this to fetch recently created top 500 items from SharePoint list:

```
Collect(AllTickets, SortByColumns(HelpDesk, "ID", SortOrder.Descending));
```

Also, you can increase the data row limit in Power Apps up to 2000 (instead of 500) from app settings:

1. Open app in edit mode and Go to App Settings:

   [image]
2. From General tab, scroll down to Data row limit settings and change it to 2000 (maximum) instead of 500

   [image]
3. Close the popup and Save/Publish your app.